# Use eval() in a Chrome chrome-extension:// page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that this may be just me being stupid, but in a Chrome tab that has a page loaded with a URL which begins with `chrome-extension://`, can the scripts be online or use `eval();`? I know that browser or page actin oopups or app windows can't use it. Part of my extension opens a normal new tab with a page which uses `eval();`.

Comment: Look at the docs for permissions in manifest

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy (I may post a proper answer later if I have time)

Comment: @ZigMandel Permissions won't change anything.

Comment: I know that an extension's popup can't use eval();  without sandboxing, but this is a regular tab that opened a file inside the extension's install directory.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "be online". I answered regarding "eval". cc @Xan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All pages running at the `chrome-extension://` origin are subject to a default content security policy described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), specifically:

```
script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'
```

A popup is considered such a page, too, as is the invisible background page. If you open a file from your extension, it will be subject to it too.

You can either:

- Relax (or tighten) the default policy for all pages with your manifest:

  ```
  "content_security_policy": "[POLICY STRING GOES HERE]"
  ```

  This way you can allow `eval` and friends by adding `'unsafe-eval'` to `script-src`.

  You can also allow loading external scripts by adding their origin to the policy; however, only HTTPS origins are allowed for MitM protection reasons.

  However, it's important to remember that `'unsafe-inline'` will be ignored regardless of your custom policy.
- Relax (or tighten) the default policy for a specific page by [declaring it sandboxed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox).

  ```
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "page1.html",
      "directory/page2.html"
    ]
    // content_security_policy is optional.
    "content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src https://www.google.com"
  ],
  ```

  Sandboxed CSP can be more permissive, but still there are a couple of restrictions.

  The price of sandboxing is losing access to Chrome API. The sandboxed script has to communicate via DOM messages with some privileged pages to do privileged things.

  There's a guide in the documentation, ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval)

---

For Apps, the situation is a bit different. Again, a default (and more restrictive) CSP applies, but [you cannot modify it in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy).

Sandboxing approach still works, though.

Answer (score 2):

To use eval, look at the policy "unsafe-eval" in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy